# How can I tell between these two buttons in Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm running Selenium on Python and I can't figure out how to tell these buttons apart so that I can click one with Selenium. I need to click option 1. I can't figure out how to get any important data tags off of them, but I'm very very new to this!

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>TOP1                                 </td>
        <td>11/16/15</td>
        <td>12/30/99</td>
        <td>Balance due on account</td>
        <td><button onclick="addNotify('RANDOMNUMBERS','option_1    ','Option1                                 ','IDNUMBER');">Add Alert</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TOP2                                        </td>
        <td>11/16/15</td>
        <td>12/30/99</td>
        <td>Balance due on account</td>
        <td><button onclick="addNotify('RANDOMNUMBERS','option_2   ','Option2                                        ','IDNUMBER');">Add Alert</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to click "Add Alert" for the button that follows TOP1

I've tried all of these (individually) and many more, but can't get any to work for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Add Hold']").click()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='button' and contains(text(), 'Add Alert')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"button\"]/descendant::span[text()='option_1    ']").click()
```

Comment: Can you please edit this question with the code itself rather than a screenshot?

Comment: There, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, 3 and 4 won't work, since they are not a correct xpath (you don't have `title` attribute, `button` is not a class, and `option_1` is not part of the button text); option 2 would return first element, so it should work for first button on the page, but usually it's better to be more specific.

If the text of the buttons is different (it's not on your HTML code, but I'm not sure it's not typo), then use:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Add Alert')]
```

otherwise use

```
//button[contains(@onclick,'option_1')]
```

If both of those xpath fail when used in `find` like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(...).click()
```

then you need to check 2 things:

1. Is this form in some sort of iframe? if it is, you need to [switch to iframe](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) before finding it
2. It can also be that button doesn't appear immediately, you need to [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for it:

   ```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"<same xpath as above>")))
   element.click()
   ```

Comment: '//button[contains(@onclick,'option_1')]' worked, thanks! I was putting @value, I didn't realize the @ was the html tag!

Answer (score 1):

The ones that you tried does not matched to whats in the markup, first you need to add classes for your buttons, if you gonna yung @class.

But still what you are doing is wrong, you need to use  List to get the rows of the table, if this table is dynamic. First add classes for your table rows and buttons:

```
<!-- Add class to your <tr> -->
<tr class="rows">
<!-- and class to you <button> -->
<button class="button" onclick="addNotify('RANDOMNUMBERS','option_1    ','Option1                                 ','IDNUMBER');">Add Alert</button>
```

The use:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rows"));
//Since you wanted the first button after TOP 1 use get index 0 (get(0))
buttons.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='button']")).click();
```